# Storing Identify Results within an array (ImageMagick running inside shell_exec)

Tags: php, linux, imagemagick, shell-exec

I am using ImageMagick to read information about various image files. I was wondering if it was possible to store the results of identify inside of an array. The reason I need to do is because of how the out put looks with gifs, as appose to one line of output it returns one for each frame which gets very muddled. I have tried multiple options but have not had much luck so far. My most recent attempt:

```
exec('identify -format "|%W" $img_temp', $output);
```

I have also tried running the above information with shell_exec as well to no avail.

If this not possible putting a unique identifier between the outputs would also be acceptable, or just limiting the result to one would also work

The question I had was if it possible to limit the results that the identify command returns.

Edit: I got it working with a unique identifier and then using explode to break it out, but I can't help but feel there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not exsactly sure what kind of output does identify but if it outputing content on diferent line could use explode("\n",$outputOfExec); and then echo the first line by echo $explodedContent[0];

```
$output = exec('identify -format "%W" $img_temp', $out);
$array = explode("\n",$output);
echo $array[0];
```

Comment: Yeah, I just did it using |, unfortunately the output is one massive string I was hoping there was a way to return an object or array.

Comment: If you do that command in cmd/terminal is it outputing on diferent line ?

Comment: @Gordnfreeman did you try to use explode("\r",$execOutput); instead

Comment: @Gordnfreeman Since you marked the awnser as correct im guessing the \r worked ?   Im currius :P

Comment: Ah yes sorry, using explode worked. I modified it slightly but the concept was the same. Instead of exploding on /n I added | between entries and exploded on that.